# udp client server in cygwin(windows) and gcc/g++ mac

Tags: c++, macos, udp, cygwin, client-server

I am an beginner in networking. I have a plan to make client server udp, using pc (window xp) as a client and mac as a server. I have made server.cc, client.cc, net.h and makefile configuration.

I use cygwin to make file in window and g++ to make in mac.

but when I make file in cygwin there are errors:

g++    -c -o server.o server.cc

CC -o udp_server server.o -lsocket -lnsl

/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lsocket

/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lnsl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

and in mac the error is:

c++    -c -o server.o server.cc

CC -o udp_server server.o -lsocket -lnsl

ld: library not found for -lsocket
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

and here are my code program of the server:

```
#include "net.h"
#include <iostream> //diilangin .h
using namespace std; //ditambah

const int  kWELL_KNOWN_PORT = 49998;
const char kMESSAGE[]  = "UDP Bye";

int main(){

// our to be server end-point, and client endpoint
   struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
   struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
   int cli_sock = 0, retval = 0; 

// need to first ask OS for free socket descriptor
// this will be the listening socket - notr SOCK_DGRAM option now
   cli_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
   if(cli_sock<0)
  cerr<<"Error when trying to create socket"<<strerror(errno)<<endl;
   else {
  // build an internet socket address structure, defining port.
  memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
  serv_addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); // any of this machines IPs will do
  serv_addr.sin_port        = htons(kWELL_KNOWN_PORT);

  // attempt to bind socket - still need to in UDP
  retval = bind(cli_sock, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
  if(retval < 0)
     cerr<<"Could not bind to port"<<endl<<strerror(errno)<<endl;
  else {
     // forever loop no more accept or listen!!!
     for(;;) {
        char buff[256];

        // get the message and display it
        //int clilen = sizeof(cli_addr); di comment
        socklen_t clilen = (socklen_t)sizeof(cli_addr);
        int len = recvfrom(cli_sock, buff, 256, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, &clilen);
        buff[len] = 0;
        cout<<"GOT "<<buff<<endl;

        // send a reply
        strcpy(buff,kMESSAGE);
        if(sendto(cli_sock, buff, strlen(buff), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, clilen) == -1)
           cerr<<"Error when sending"<<endl<<strerror(errno)<<endl;
     }
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Do any one have suggestions to improve my programs?

daniel

Answer (score 0):

There is no -lsocket (libsocket) on cygwin. Can you try adding:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
```

... to your header? sys/socket.h comes standard with Cygwin.

I hope this is helpful!